# Minimum Product Spanning Tree with Negatives?

Tags: graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I understand that you can find the MPT by taking the log of every edge in the graph and calculating the MST.  The constraint here of course is that the values of the edges must be positive, because you cannot take `log(x)` where `x <= 0`.  I am trying to find an algorithm that can be used to calculate the MPT when edge values can be positive, zero, or negative, but I couldn't find any resources online that would explain how to handle this case.  Can someone either provide a resource or algorithm that allows for MPT to be calculated when the positive constraint is lifted?  Alternatively, if someone can provide a hint in the right direction so that I could figure out the algorithm independently, that would work too.